# Determine "active" ActiveX control

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using VBA, how can I determine the ActiveX control currently selected in a Word document while in Design Mode? That would be the control for which the properties are offered in the context menu.

Comment: Easy.  If code is running, you aren't in Design Mode - executing VBA takes Word out of Design Mode.

Comment: Do you mean *programmatically*?

Comment: I'm Comintern is right. Code can't run while in Design mode and when Design mode is turned off the focus on any previously selected control is lost. My code is turning on design mode and selecting a specific control, but the reverse doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible. While a control is selected Word is in Design Mode and code can't execute. When not in design mode no control is selected.